# Execute function on bringing app from sleep

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I'm sure this is something very straight forward but I can't find the information anywhere. I need my app to reload some information when it is opened from the background (not a fresh open). Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 5):

Your app can override `- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application` in your `UIApplicationDelegate`.

You also have your controller become an observer for [UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html). According to Apple Docs: *Posted shortly before an application leaves the background state on its way to becoming the active application.*

Sample code with controller in NIB file, otherwise override `- (id)init`:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(wakeUp:) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)wakeUp:(NSNotification *)pNotification {
    NSLog(@"Name: %@", [pNotification name]);
    NSLog(@"Object: %@", [pNotification object]);
    NSLog(@"I am waking up");
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: That sounds perfect. Any ideas how I could get this to fire in my view controller?

Comment: Here's an example of what I want to do: my user is in the app, clicks the home button to open safari or something, then clicks on my app again. This should trigger a reload.

Comment: For some reason it works when i register it in - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated. But obviously that's not ideal

Comment: If you controller is not in a NIB, you will have to override `- (id)init`.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the documentation for `applicationDidBecomeActive` and `applicationWillEnterForeground` in the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: That sounds perfect. Any ideas how I could get this to fire in my view controller?